# How to stream Internet radio in a browser?

Tags: internet-radio

I am trying to stream a Internet radio station using a browser. It appears like it is loading but I don't hear any sound. This is the station I am trying to stream: http://tunein.com/tuner/?StationId=68906 (It is a regional radio station and is in Tamil.)

When I try to stream it in Rhythmbox, I get the following error message:

> Required plugin could not be found Python (v2.7) requires to install
>   plugins to play media files of the following type: text/html decoder

I don't think this is a network firewall problem because I can listen to the radio when I am on Windows 7. I am expecting it to be an issue of a missing plugin.

Comment: Works here in Firefox 9, default Totem plugin.

Comment: Works directly in VLC also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install [GStreamer plugins for mms, wavpack, quicktime, musepack](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad) [image: Install gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad].

After restarting the browser and clicking the link, it asked to install [gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg) [image: Install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg] and Chromium played the stream.

Comment: I just purged the gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad and gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg and reinstalled it and the radio is working fine. Thanks!

Comment: I have both plugins installed, yet not working on google chrome. I was trying to listen to http://rvlradio.com/#index.php?pageName=rock

Comment: I was getting the same error. I removed gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg refreshed the page and the radio worked.